# Convert days to weeks and month

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

1st method: I've got x days and I want to convert it to weeks and month via php. For example 24 days:

3 weeks 3 days

or 45 days:

that's where my problem starts. How can I know that 45 days is how many month including month differentials?

2nd method: I've got two dates, for example 2020-05-13 and 2020-07-14. Can I calculate month, weeks, and days somehow from these?

I don't have any code since I don't even know how to start it.

Comment: What is the source of the data?

Comment: You mean the dates? From a MySQL database.

Comment: OK thanks. Have a look at the duplicate questions that it was closed with. If those didn't help you solve this, consider editing your post to contain what the schema and values are.

Comment: that's now exactly what I want because I want weeks as well. Its only years, month, and days. What do you suggest?